Sound card not working after installing pulseaudio_equalizer
I plugged new speakers to my laptop and installed PulseAudio_equalizer for playing with the sound as I wished, but since then I don't have sound anymore and when looking at the hardware it's not the same as before. Things are missing and all is 'generic".
Screenshots here https://www.swisstransfer.com/d/3ea67c1d-bc98-45c7-9572-23eeef8a9377




